# Git workspace on OSX (case insensitive but preserving) have pulled case-related changes

Tags: git, macos

My colleague has pushed changes where a java package (directory) like /fooBar/ was renamed to /foobar/

In my git OSX workspace, this code no longer compiles.

What is easiest way to force a workspace to get the directories with the updated case?

**EDIT:** *Originally I thought that 'git mv' was a option, but now understand that approach is actually for changing case myself of CM-ed files in my workspaces 
I see at  http://salferrarello.com/git-case-sensitive-rename/*

```
git mv FileName.txt filename.tmp
git mv filename.tmp filename.txt
git add filename.txt
gc -m 'case change of filename'
```

*but I want a local change that wont require a git commit.*

**/Edit**

In svn I could I think delete the 'bad' directory and update it from central repo.

Comment: His code updates were okay; it was just that my workspace wasn't updating because it wasn't changing case of directories. But all okay with the approach in VonC answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to:

- delete (as you mention for svn)
- git pull
- and/or update the working tree with a `git checkout -- foobar/`